# Node.js mysql insert into multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I am using an AWS Node.js lambda function and I am attempting to insert into multiple tables in my MySQL database. I am using the mysql node package. I have two tables (header and detail) in the database. I have an array of JSON objects that includes the header info with an array of the detail info inside the object. It looks like this:

```
{
  id:1,
  name: "bob",
  detail: [salary: 50000, age: 35]
}, {
  id:1,
  name: "jane",
  detail: [salary: 60000, age: 28]
}
```

I need to loop through each object in this array and populate:

1. header table (id and name)
2. detail table for that header (salary, age)

I tried using the standard "mysql" library for Node.js, but due to the nature of the connectoin.query(sql, fn), the second parameter is a callback, and I'm not sure how I would pull this off. I'm not sure how I could loop through the headers and details within the headers using the standard mysql library since the .query function requires a callback and not a Promise

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `promisify` utility from the nodejs utils package to wrap the mysql (or specific functions in the module) in a Promise, allowing you to use async/await. Something like this:

```
    const mysql = require('mysql')
    const util = require('util')
    const pool = mysql.createPool({ ... })
    ...
    pool.query = util.promisify(pool.query)
    ...
    try {
    var result = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM users')
    } catch(err) {
        throw new Error(err)
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I actually considered `promisify`. I have also looked at mysql2, which DOES support query promises. My only concern with mysql2 is the legitimacy and stability of that package vs. the standard mysql library that is typically used

Comment: I'd simply promisify the standard mysql-lib shown in the code sample -> https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql

Maybe check out https://medium.com/@mhagemann/create-a-mysql-database-middleware-with-node-js-8-and-async-await-6984a09d49f4